# Nodejs 16 Google Cloud Function resulting in intermittent "Truncated response body."

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a QR code `onRequest` Google Cloud Function, running on 2nd Gen. I'm using the [qrcode package](https://github.com/soldair/node-qrcode) to generate simple QR codes like the one you see here.

[image]

2nd gen GCF's are capable of handling a massive amount of calls. However, while most QR codes return to the calling program, many return as a black square, rather than a QR code, and then in GCF logs I'm seeing this message:

> Truncated response body. Usually implies that the request timed out or the application exited before the response was finished.

As you can see in code below, I have 1 instance always running, plenty of processing power, and there should be no timeout issues to generate these super simplistic QR codes png's on the fly.

Out of a 1,000 calls, only about 5% result in a black square and the `Truncated response` message.

I'm wondering if I've got some kind of Promise issue and not await'ing properly? Also wondering, what is generating this Truncated message? The GCF trace does not give any more details.

Note: the data sent to be encoded in the QR code is always the same format, which is an int.

**qrCode.ts script for GCF**

```js
import { onRequest } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https'
import { logger } from 'firebase-functions/v2'

import QRCode from 'qrcode'
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import { kDebug } from './lib/constants'
import { normalizedSku } from './lib/helperFunctions'

const app = express()

// Automatically allow cross-origin requests
app.use(cors({ origin: true }))
// Support json encoded bodies and url encoded bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// Save the qrcode to memory in GCF and return as a file
const filepath = '/tmp/qrcode.png'

/**
 * Save the QR code to file.
 * @param {string} qrCodePlainText The plain text that makes up QR code.
 * @param {unknown} options The QR code package options.
 * @return {boolean} Whether the QR code was saved to file.
 */
async function saveQrCodeToFile(qrCodePlainText: string, options: unknown): Promise<boolean> {
  try {
    await QRCode.toFile(filepath, qrCodePlainText, options)
    return true
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error)
    return false
  }
}

/**
 * QR Code image generator. The value in GET will be decoded and set as the plain text in the
 * generated qr code, which is returned as a png.
 *
 * https://github.com/soldair/node-qrcode
 */
app.get('/qrCode/:data', async (req, res) => {
  let qrCodeData = req.params.data
  // Inches, e.g. a value of 1 will result in a 1"x1" qrcode. The max is 10.
  const inchesParam = req.query.inches
  const returnToDataUrl = req.query.returnToDataUrl === 'true'
  const isSku = req.query.isSku === 'true'

  try {
    if (kDebug) {
      logger.info('req.params', req.params)
      logger.info('req.query', req.query)
    }

    if (!qrCodeData) {
      throw Error('Missing QR Code data param')
    }

    if (!inchesParam) {
      throw Error('Missing inches param')
    }

    // Will return NaN if not a number
    const inches = parseFloat(inchesParam as string)

    if (isNaN(inches)) {
      throw Error(`${inchesParam} is not a number`)
    }

    if (kDebug) {
      logger.info(`QR Code dimensions: ${inches}"x${inches}"`)
    }

    if (inches > 10) {
      throw Error('Inches param cannot be greater than 10')
    }

    // If this is a sku then normalize the data
    if (isSku) {
      qrCodeData = normalizedSku(qrCodeData)
    }

    const options = {
      margin: 2,
    }

    // Convert inches to pixels for digital devices. 1" = 96px
    options['width'] = Math.round(inches * 96)

    if (kDebug) {
      logger.info(options)
    }

    const qrCodePlainText = decodeURIComponent(qrCodeData)

    if (returnToDataUrl) {
      res.send(await QRCode.toDataURL(qrCodePlainText))
      return
    } else {
      if (!(await saveQrCodeToFile(qrCodePlainText, options))) {
        throw Error(`QR code failed for ${qrCodeData}.`)
      }
      res.sendFile(filepath)
    }
  } catch (e) {
    if (kDebug) {
      logger.error(e)
    }

    res.status(400).send(e.toString())
  }
})

exports.endpoint = onRequest(
  { timeoutSeconds: 60, region: ['us-east4'], memory: '2GiB', minInstances: 1 },
  app,
)
```

#### Updated saveQrCodeToFile() function using callback:

```js
/**
 * Save the QR code to file.
 * @param {string} qrCodePlainText The plain text that makes up QR code.
 * @param {unknown} options The QR code package options.
 * @return {boolean} Whether the QR code was saved to file.
 */
async function saveQrCodeToFile(qrCodePlainText: string, options: unknown): Promise<boolean> {
  try {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      QRCode.toFile(filepath, qrCodePlainText, options, error => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error)
        }

        resolve(true)
      })
    })
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error)
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: Which path is the code taking?  Add some logging to find out which lines are getting executed when the failure occurs.

Comment: Adding some logging is a good idea. It is taking the saveQrCodeToFile() route. So, a png is created and I'm sending the QR code png to the browser res.sendFile(filepath). Note: I'm not getting the throw Error(`QR code failed for... message, so, the error is being caught by try / catch.

Comment: toFile doesn't return a promise, so you can't await it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[toFile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode#tofilepath-text-options-cberror) doesn't return a promise.  It uses a callback API, and you're not specifying a callback, so your code goes on to try to send the file before it might be done writing.

Comment: Changed my code to use the callback, within a Promise. Good catch. Not sure why I thought it was async and I could await.